# Factor theorem and polynomial solution

Tags: polynomials, factoring

Find the value of $m$ if $(x-m)$ is a factor of $x^2-m^2 x+x+2$. I know if $(x-m)$ is a factor of $f (x)$ then $f(m)$ must be zero.  But I could not reduce it.

Comment: Please could you format the polynomial? It's not clear whether it's: $x^2-m^2 x+x+2 $ or$ x^2-m^{2x}+x+2$ for example :)

Comment: If $f(x-m)$ is a factor, $f(m)$ is a zero - What do you mean by $f(a)$ is a zero? What is "a"?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Notice, $(x-m)$ is a factor of $x^2-m^2\cdot x+x+2$ then substituting $x=m$, the value of the polynomial should be zero, hence we get $$(m)^2-m^2(m)+m+2=0$$ $$m^3-m^2-m-2=0$$
You can solve above cubic equation for real value of $m$ using Newton's Method which gives $m=2$ real root hence factorizing the polynomial $$(m-2)(m^2+m+1)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

When you divide $x^2-m^2x+x+2$ by $(x-m)$, you get-

the quotient part is $=x-m^2+1+m$, and the remainder part is $=2-m^3+m^2+m$.

Since, $(x-m)$ is a factor, the remainder part has to be zero.

The equation, $m^3-m^2-m-2$, has $3$ roots, namely- $m_1=2, \ m_2=-0.5(1+\sqrt 3i) \text{ and } m_3 =-0.5(1-\sqrt 3i)$.

Knowing the values of $m$, you can write the expression of the factor $(x-m)$ using the appropriate numerical value e.g. $(x-2)$.

Answer (score 0):

You have  that $f(m)={m}^{2}-{m}^{3}+m+2=- \left( m-2 \right)  \left( {m}^{2}+m+1 \right)=0.$
Thus $m=2$ or  $m$ is a root of the equation ${m}^{2}+m+1=0.$